# Mongo DB - How to get group products on the base of supplier?

Tags: mongodb

I need your help. Given the structure below I need to query the
document in a way to get all 'products' for a given supplier.

```
{
    "supplier" : [ 
        {"name" : "supplier 1",
            "products" : [
                { "name" : "product 1" }
                { "name" : "product 2" }
            ]
        },
        {
         "name" : "supplier 1",
             "products" : [
                { "name" : "product 3" }
            ]
        },
        {
         "name" : "supplier 2",
             "products" : [
                { "name" : "product 3" }
            ]
        },
    ]
}
```

The resulting document for 'supplier 1' should
be the following (or similar).

```
{
    "products" : [
        { "name" : "product 1" },
        { "name" : "product 2" },
        { "name" : "product 3" }
    ]
      
}
```

The result should only contain unique values for the `products`.
What is a good server side solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `$unwind` deconstruct `supplier` array
- `$group` by `supplier.name` and make array of `products`
- `$project` to show required fields, `$reduce` to iterate loop of `products` and concat arrays or product using `$concatArrays`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$supplier" },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$supplier.name",
      products: { $push: "$supplier.products" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: "$_id",
      products: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$products",
          initialValue: [],
          in: { $concatArrays: ["$$this", "$$value"] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/8Ut3FTJJZmz)

Comment: Thank you very much! That works perfectly. I did not know the $reduce/$concathArrays feature. That was really helpful! merry chrismas turivishal